# spring data elasticsearch can't deserialize array of objects

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring data elasticsearch to search elasticsearch(7.12.1) documents:

- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch: 2.7.0, which uses
- spring-data-elasticsearch: 4.4.0

and find **spring data elasticsearch can deserialize [array field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) of basic type correctly but not custom object**.

Here comes the issue--

A simple Person index with two fields may be array, one is basic string `hobbies` and the other is custom object `children`(**there is no need to use nested object for me, plain object is enough**):

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(indexName = "person", writeTypeHint = WriteTypeHint.FALSE, createIndex = true)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Set<String> hobbies;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Set<Child> children;

    @Data
    public static class Child {
        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String name;
    }
}
```

it creates mappings automatically as expected:

```
{
  "person" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "children" : {
          "properties" : {
            "name" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "hobbies" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

put 4 docs manually now:

```
PUT person/_doc/one-hobby
{
  "hobbies": "one"
}

PUT person/_doc/two-hobbies
{
  "hobbies": ["one", "two"]
}
PUT person/_doc/one-child
{
  "children": {"name": "name1"}
}

PUT person/_doc/two-children
{
  "children": [{"name": "name1"}, {"name": "name2"}]
}
```

Then query them one by one by their ids using `ElasticsearchRepository#findById(id)`, the two docs with array values deserialize ok:

```
Person(id=two-children, hobbies=null, children=[Person.Child(name=name1), Person.Child(name=name2)])
Person(id=two-hobbies, hobbies=[one, two], children=null)
```

This is understandable because convert arrays to `Set` in java seems natural.

the one with only a basic field deserializes is ok too:

```
Person(id=one-hobby, hobbies=[one], children=null)
```

Although it convers a single string to `Set`, I've seen some of the deserializing source code, spring-data-elasticsearch uses `string to collection converter` to convert the single value `hobbies` into arraied-one, thus `hobbies` field in java as a `Set` behaves well.

but the one with only a custom object field(id=one-child) can't be deserialized:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.instantiateClass(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:320)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.readValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:458)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.readValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader$ElasticsearchPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader$ElasticsearchPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:313)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:320)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Reader.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:745)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.get(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.lambda$findById$0(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.execute(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:355)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.findById(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.findById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.findById(Unknown Source)
    at io.puppylpg.PersonOps.get(PersonOps.java:23)
    at io.puppylpg.App.main(App.java:43)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.Set]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.instantiateClass(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:112)
    ... 54 more
```

Seems that spring-data-elasticsearch won't try to convert custom object into `Set` because in `MappingElasticsearchConverter` **if value is a map(a custom object), it just tries to read it directly**, thus doesn't go the last line `getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead`(thus doesn't use some kine of `custom object to collection converter` like before):

```
        private <T> T readValue(Object value, TypeInformation<?> type) {

            Class<?> rawType = type.getType();

            if (conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(value.getClass(), rawType)) {
                return (T) conversionService.convert(value, rawType);
            } else if (value instanceof List) {
                return (T) readCollectionOrArray(type, (List<Object>) value);
            } else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
                return (T) readCollectionOrArray(type, Arrays.asList((Object[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof Map) {
                return (T) read(type, (Map<String, Object>) value);
            } else {
                return (T) getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(value, rawType);
            }
        }
```

Is this supported in spring data elasticsearch? And any ideas to fix this problem or work around it?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when using a `List`? If so, do you need a set instead of a list?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch same error, except that error info is changed to `MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments`

Answer (score 2):

Can youplease create an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues, best with a sample repo that reproduces the error?

**Update 29.08.2022:** This has been fixed and will be released with the next maintenance releases of branches 4.4 and 4.3.

Comment: Sure, i planed to create a issue before asking here, but thinked it was such a common case that may have solution already. Now i think spring-data-elasticsearch should add some suppport for detecting "single object or array" when deserializing a field.